# Using Range.Replace on Formula Cells

Tags: excel, vba

I have a short list of values from **A1** through **A10**:

[image]

**A4** contains the string `ab` and **A5** contains the formula:

```
="a" & "b"
```

If I run:

```
Sub Test1()
    Dim r As Range

    Set r = Range("A1:A10")
    r.Replace What:="ab", Replacement:="x"
End Sub
```

only **A4** gets modified.

How can I get the Replace Method to work for both cases ??

**EDIT#1:**

I can always use a loop to examine/replace item-by-item, but `.Replace` is much faster.  I suppose that I could build and use a temporary AutoFilter, but this seems extreme.

Comment: Do you need the formulas in A1:A10 after the replacement? Are there other formulas that need to stay? If not, you could first replace all formulas with values, `range("A1:A10").value = range("A1:A10").value`, then `r.Replace` would work as you want. As far as I know, there is no possibility to have replace look at values only.

Comment: @Sun  There are other formulas in the column that I do not wish to change..................I can always resort to using a loop, but this would be slow for large columns.............thanks for responding..........

Comment: using `.Find` might speed up your loop (you'd have a do-while-loop)

Comment: @Sun  ..........Thank you............it's a good compromise..........

Comment: It is an ancient thread, but it could be done as initially wonted, but in two steps: Firstly, `What:="=""a"" & ""b"""` and secondly `What:="ab"`...

Comment: @FaneDuru  .....clever idea! ......................thanks!

Comment: I must confess that I became 'cleverer' after I made a comment saying that "I am not sure that **VBA** range Replace function works for formulas". Without testing. I do not remember how such an idea has been sticked on my brain. Documenting myself a little better, I discovered that it works **only** for formulas...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is what I have created:

```
Option Explicit

Sub TestMe()

    Dim myCell As Range
    Dim myText As String

    For Each myCell In Worksheets(1).Range("A1:A10")
        If InStr(myCell.Text, "ab") > 0 Then
            myText = myCell.Text
            myCell = Replace(myText, "ab", "x")
            myCell.Value = myText
        End If
    Next myCell

End Sub
```

Answer (score 6):

Interesting problem, it seems that a `LookIn` option would be nice.

I tried a few things (all using loops however). I disabled screenupdating for all the tests.

Using `Replace`:

```
r.Replace what:="ab", Replacement:="x"
```

using `Find`:

```
Dim c As Range
Set c = r.Find(what:="ab", LookIn:=xlValues)
While Not (c Is Nothing)
    c.Value = "x"
    Set c = r.FindNext
Wend
```

using a simple loop:

```
Dim i As Long
For i = 1 To 10
    If Cells(i, 1).Value = "ab" Then Cells(i, 1).Value = "x"
Next i
```

Using a better loop:

```
Dim c as Range
    For Each c In r.Cells
    If c.Value = "ab" Then c.Value = "x"
Next c
```

Using an array to search:

```
Dim v As Variant
Dim i as Long
v = r.Value
For i = 1 to 10
    If v(i,1) = "ab" Then Cells(i,1).Value = "x"
next i
```

The `Replace` and array method were the fastest to search the range and I didn't notice any speed difference. However, the writing to the cells slowed down the loops considerably when there were many replacements to do (it got noticeable somewhere around 5000 replacements out of 1,000,000 values for me).
The `Find` suffered heavy from more replacements and the other two loops were much slower when searching.

Conclusion: Using an internal array is the best way (that I can think of. It even beats removing all the formulas first (`r.Value = r.Value`).

Maybe saving all the occurrences and replacing them after the loop could speed things up further.

Comment: Thank you! ..................Using an internal VBA array seems to be he way to go!

Answer (score 2):

also you can use this:

```
Sub ThereIsAnotherOneVariant()
    With [A1:A10]
        .Value2 = .Value2
        .Replace "ab", "x"
    End With
End Sub
```

but this variant will remove all formulas in the range

Answer (score 0):

Even if this is a historical thread, I think it is good to emphasize that fastest method (`Replace`), works very well for solving the question in discussion, without any iteration. In fact, range 'Replace' method works **Only** for string formulas... But due to the fact that `Formula` property of a range without formula returns its text, it works also in that case, too. It only searches and replaces twice, but it needs the exact formula string like `What` parameter:

```
Sub Test1_Bis()
    Dim r As Range

    Set r = Range("A1:A10")
    r.Replace What:="=""a"" & ""b""", Replacement:="x"
    r.Replace What:="ab", Replacement:="x"
End Sub
```